rosbag tf2 transform has timestamp zero
I am writing a node that is listening to the transforms between a camera_optical_link and base_link. My plan was to analyze the recorded rosbag with this node, however upon inspection the timestamp for the transform between camera_left_rgb_optical_frame with the base_link at any point in time is zero in the rosbag. I cannot proceed to analyze the rosbag using the node written since it requires nonzero time, I'm sure there is something wrong somewhere.
$ rosrun tf tf_echo /base_link /camera_left_rgb_optical_frame
At time 0.000
- Translation: [0.186, -0.019, 1.455]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [-0.690, 0.153, -0.153, 0.690]
            in RPY (radian) [-1.571, -0.000, -0.437]
            in RPY (degree) [-90.000, -0.000, -25.027]
At time 0.000
- Translation: [0.186, -0.019, 1.455]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [-0.690, 0.153, -0.153, 0.690]
            in RPY (radian) [-1.571, -0.000, -0.437]
            in RPY (degree) [-90.000, -0.000, -25.027]
At time 0.000
- Translation: [0.186, -0.019, 1.455]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [-0.690, 0.153, -0.153, 0.690]
            in RPY (radian) [-1.571, -0.000, -0.437]
            in RPY (degree) [-90.000, -0.000, -25.027]
...

